# Hiding/Unhiding worksheets that change monthly

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for some help with a  monthly report that I run. I am attempting to automate the report to cut down on some manual labor time! Currently, I run a large monthly report that can be daunting. One area I am struggling with is automatically hiding/unhiding worksheets in the workbook as I'm trying to pull a different month each month. I have already prepopulated the worksheets for JAN - DEC 18 and am looking for a way to where I don't have to hide/unhide sheets manually.

I have currently created a userform in which the month is selected via a combobox (FormMonth). The user can select JAN - DEC. I have also have created a separate textbox where the user can enter the year they are searching for.

EX: Attempting to unhide worksheets. I am currently trying to unhide a worksheet labeled JUL18. I have attempted the following code:

```
worksheets(" " & FormMonth & "18").visible = true
```

I have also tried

```
worksheets(" " & FormMonth & "18").visible = xlvisible
```

I'm not having any luck and was hoping someone would be willing to lend a hand. For bonus, any help on how I can automatically code to hide previous months sheets as well would be great! For example, if I'm unhiding JUL18 sheets, how would I code to hide JUN18 worksheets.

Thanks,

Derek

Comment: Change `worksheets(" " & FormMonth & "18").visible = true` to `worksheets(FormMonth & 18).visible = true`

Comment: Just to confirm, when you are running `Debug.Print FormMonth` , are you getting `Jul` in the immediate window ?

Comment: Try `Worksheets(FormMonth & "18").Visible = xlSheetHidden` or `xlSheetVisible`

Comment: Why are you concatenating an extra space before your worksheet name? Is your worksheet actually named `" JUL18"`? Put a breakpoint on this line (place cursor on line and press `F9`) and then when it hits the breakpoint, go to your `Immediate` pane and type `?FormMonth & "18"` and hit enter. Does it spit out `"JUL18"`?

Comment: Hello and thanks for all the feedback! I'm on about week 3 of working with vba and its quite a learning curve! All of the feedback was great and I just had some wrong syntax. I removed the spacing prior to FormMonth and it works like a gem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sub shows the worksheet for the selected month and hide all others.
Note that it sets first the sheet to visible and only after that hides the rest - else you risk that you try to hide *all* sheets and that will fail.

```
Sub showMonthSheet(mon As String)
    Const year = "18"

    Dim sheetname As String
    sheetname = mon & " " & year

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Visible = True

    Dim ws As Worksheet    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> sheetname Then
            ws.Visible = False
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

(I assume that your worksheet names are like **Jan 18** without leading or trailing blank, but with a blank between month name and year)

Comment: I think this `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Visible = True` will fail if there is no sheet named `sheetname` in the workbook.

Comment: If your FormMonth is "JUL18", previous month sheet can get using ucase(MonthName(Month("1 " & left(FormMonth,3) & " " & Right(FormMonth,2)) -1, true)) & "18"